# Output multidimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array `$myArr['words']` that stores data like this:

```php
Array (
    [above-the-fold] => Array
    (
        [term] => Above the fold
        [desc] => The region of a Web ...
    )

    [active-voice] => Array
    (
        [term] => Active voice
        [desc] => Makes subjects do ...
    )

    [anchor-links] => Array
    (
        [term] => Anchor links
        [desc] => Used on content ....
    )
)
```

I need to out put it like this:

```php
echo '
<a href="#'.$myArr['above-the-fold].'">
    '.$myArr['above-the-fold]['term'].'
</a>';
```

... for each term. Here's what I've tried:

```php
$arrLen = count($myArr['words']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $arrLen; $i++) {
    foreach ($myArr['words'][$i] as $trm => $dsc) {
        echo $trm;
    }
}
```

But even this does not output the list of terms. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` is your friend here.

```
foreach($myArr['words'] as $k => $v) {
    echo '
    <a href="#'.$k.'">
        '.$v['term'].'
    </a>';
}
```

This takes each of the elements in your array in turn, e.g. the first loop will have:

```
/*
[above-the-fold] => Array
(
    [term] => Above the fold
    [desc] => The region of a Web ...
)

So: 

$k = 'above-the-fold'
$v = Array
     (
        [term] => Above the fold
        [desc] => The region of a Web ...
     )
*/
```

Comment: As always I'm overthinking it... Thanks.